# Bootstrap Toggler blocking Accordion Toggler?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Problem: I am designing a page using bootstrap 5/html/css. I made it responsive so with a specific width the boostrap 5 menu with toggler navbar shows. On the rest of the page, I want to add an accordion style menu. I've done tests and I know that there is nothing wrong with the code seperatly, but when I put them both on the same page and I click on the accordion tab to show, the page scrolls back up to the head. I think it has to do with the toggler navbar code, but I'm a student so I don't really know how to solve this so I came to ask you guys for help! Thanks :)

Here is the HTML:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>eyo</title>
    <!---CSS BOOTSTRAP--->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--FONTAWESOME-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9e552d07ce.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <!-- NavBar -->
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class=" container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- 
        target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
        label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" src=""><i class="fas fa-sort-down fa-3x"></i></span>
    </button>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="" class=" logo d-inline-block align-top">
    <a href=""><i class="user-mobile align-top fas fa-user fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
          <button class="navbtn btn btn-lg me-2" type="button">Home</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button class="navbtn btn btn-lg me-2" type="button">Serviços</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button class="navbtn btn btn-lg me-2" type="button">Sobre</button>
        </li> 
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button class="navbtn btn btn-lg me-2" type="button">Contato</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button class="navbtn btn btn-lg me-2" type="button">Minha Conta</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </ul>
    </div>     
   <a href=""><i class="user-desktop align-top fas fa-user fa-2x"></i>

</nav>

<div id="top">
  <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="first" src="first-img.png" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
          <p class="nossos">Nossos serviços são</p>
          <span>inteiramente </span><span style="color:green; background-color: white;">ONLINE</span>
          <p class="confira">Confira abaixo!</p>
      
          </div>
      </div>
      
  </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/*NAV BAR ELEMENTS*/
.navbar{
background-color: white;
}
.logo{
    width: 50px;
    height: 44px;
}

.user-desktop{
    width: 50px;
    height: 44px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
}
.user-mobile{
    width: 50px;
    height: 44px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
}
.navbtn{
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 3px;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon{
    color: green;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
}
.navbar-nav{
    position: absolute;
}

/*TOP*/
.first{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
p{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    }

.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 56%;
    left: 70%;
    transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font-family: Ubuntu-Bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 5vw;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-top: -5.449396133422852px;
}

.servicos-title{
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

.servicos-med{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}


@media (min-width:320px)  {
    .user-desktop{
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (min-width:481px)  {
    .user-desktop{
        display: none;
    }
   
} 
@media (min-width:641px)  {
    .user-desktop{
        display: none;
    }
    
} 
@media (min-width:990px)  {
    .user-mobile{
        display: none;
    }
    .user-desktop{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
} 

@media (min-width:1025px) { 
    .user-mobile{
        display: none;
    }
    .user-desktop{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
 }   
@media (min-width:1281px) { 
    .user-mobile{
        display: none;
    }
    .user-desktop{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I don't see the accordion HTML? Also the existing code is not properly structure the closing tags are missing or nested wrong.

Comment: As Zim noted, your code has problems - there's no !DOCTYPE at the start (at least for the code you pasted) and at least one of your CSS selectors is missing, and some closing tags are missing. Try running your code through the [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) to find your errors.